# Adding objects algorithm in Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays

I have this array that has five random numbers between one to ten:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        [arrayOfNumbers addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%10]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfNumbers);
```

I want to take the first two and the last two objects and add them together. If they do add together, I want to return 2. If they don't add together, I want to check to see if the second and third object add up the last two objects. So basically if I have the array [2,3,9,4,1] then i want to check to see if 2+3=4+1. In this case, yes, so I would return 2. In this array [2,3,6,4,5] 2+3!=4+5 so we would move onto check if 3+6=4+5 and since it is we return 2. Now if there are no two objects that when added together can be equal [0,1,2,3,4] then we would return -1.

This is what I have done so far:

```
    int lastValue = [arrayOfNumbers count];
    int secondlastValue = [arrayOfNumbers count] - 1;
    int firstValue = 0;
    int secondValue = 1;

    int i;
for (i = 0; i < [arrayOfNumbers count]; i++) {
    int one = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:firstValue + i] integerValue];
    int two = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:secondValue + i] integerValue];
    int secondtolast = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:secondlastValue] integerValue];
    int last = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:lastValue] integerValue];

    if (one + two == secondtolast + last) {
        NSLog(@"2: Because %i + %i = %i + %i",firstValue,secondValue,secondlastValue,lastValue);
        break;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"-1");
    }
}
```

But for some reason, it crashes... Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

**EDIT**: this is the error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'`

**EDIT 2:**
These are my NSLog's

```
if ((one + two) == totalOfLastValues) {
            NSLog(@"2: Because %@ + %@ (%i) = %@ + %@",arrayOfNumbers[i],arrayOfNumbers[i+1],one+two,[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2],[arrayOfNumbers lastObject]);
            break;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"-1: Because %@ + %@ (%i) != %@ + %@",arrayOfNumbers[i],arrayOfNumbers[i+1],one+two,[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2],[arrayOfNumbers lastObject]);
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks like it generates an index beyond bounds exception. Why are you looping through the array and adding i to firstvalue and secondvalue? You should set a breakpoint and step through your code so you understand how it behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because the final value thing `i` points to is the last item in the array. So the final thing you attempt to look up is `secondValue+i`, which is one past the last item in the array. That raises the exception.

Similarly, your `lastValue` and `secondLastValue` are set to be one too high. The first item in an array is item `0`. So if there are two items then the last item is item `1`. If there are `n` items then the last item is `n-1`.

So:

```
        int lastValue = [arrayOfNumbers count] - 1;
        int secondlastValue = [arrayOfNumbers count] - 2;
        int firstValue = 0;
        int secondValue = 1;

        int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [arrayOfNumbers count]-1; i++) {
        int one = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:firstValue + i] integerValue];
        int two = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:secondValue + i] integerValue];
        int secondtolast = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:secondlastValue] integerValue];
        int last = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:lastValue] integerValue];

        if (one + two == secondtolast + last) {
            NSLog(@"2: Because %i + %i = %i + %i",firstValue,secondValue,secondlastValue,lastValue);
            break;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"-1");
        }
    }
```

EDIT: you also want to avoid considering whether the last two numbers added together equal the last two numbers added together. Otherwise you'll just always return 2. There's also no point doing that part of the arithmetic inside the loop. So a first neatened version might look like:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        [arrayOfNumbers addObject: @(arc4random_uniform(10))];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfNumbers);

    int lastValue = [[arrayOfNumbers lastObject] integerValue];
    int secondLastValue = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2] integerValue];
    int totalOfLastValues = lastValue + secondLastValue;
    int firstValue = 0;
    int secondValue = 1;

        int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [arrayOfNumbers count]-3; i++) {
        int one = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:firstValue + i] integerValue];
        int two = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:secondValue + i] integerValue];

        if ((one + two) == totalOfLastValues) {
            NSLog(@"2: Because %i + %i (%i) = %i",firstValue+i,secondValue+i,one+two,totalOfLastValues);
            break;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"-1");
        }
    }
```

Cleaning up and preventing duplicate calls to `integerValue` leads to:

```
    int lastValue = [[arrayOfNumbers lastObject] integerValue];
    int secondLastValue = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2] integerValue];
    int totalOfLastValues = lastValue + secondLastValue;

    int mostRecentValue  = [arrayOfNumbers[0] integerValue];
    for (int i = 1; i < [arrayOfNumbers count]-3; i++) {
        int one = mostRecentValue;
        int two = [arrayOfNumbers[i] integerValue];
        mostRecentValue = two;

        if ((one + two) == totalOfLastValues) {
            NSLog(@"2: Because %i + %i (%i) = %i",i,i+1,one+two,totalOfLastValues);
            break;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"-1");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but the nslog returned the array `(
    5,
    6,
    6,
    9,
    6
)`
and then returned `-1` twice and finally
`2: Because 0 + 1 = 3 + 4`

Comment: In that case it's added indices 2 and 3 to produce the same as indices 3 and 4 — `6 + 9 = 9 + 6`. In my edit I restricted the upper limit on `i` to avoid that.

Comment: hmm.. the array was `(
    3,
    6,
    0,
    6,
    5
)` but somehow it still NSLogged `-1` three times and then `2: Because 3 + 4 (11) = 11` even though 3 and 4 aren't even in the array

Comment: @ShalinShah your `NSLog` logs the indices, not the values. I didn't change that, assuming it to be what you intended.

Comment: I'm just learning Objective-C so would you mind showing me how to `NSLog` the values instead of indices?

Comment: The easiest solution would be instead of passing `i` and `i+1` to your NSLog to output as type `%i`, use type `%@` (it outputs any object) and supply `arrayOfNumbers[i]` and `arrayOfNumbers[i+1]`. The square brackets to access array elements is a relatively new addition to Objective-C — just reading it the same as `[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i]` will do here.

Comment: thanks! and also, how can i make `one+two` be a value? since I cant add `arrayOfNumbers[i]` and `arrayOfNumbers[i+1]`